# Why have multiple use statements in class

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.5

I'm curious about how `use` statements work in PHP. I was watching a tutorial and the code looked like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ConversationTest extends TestCase {

    use DatabaseTransactions;

}
```

Why does the `DatabaseTransactions` item have to be declared twice?

Comment: `use DatabaseTransactions;` is a trait. `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;` is an actual class.

Comment: @Andrew-- thanks. So in this example, the first `use` is sort of like a `require_once` to bring in the class with the trait in it, and the second one initializes (for lack of a better word) the trait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `use DatabaseTransactions;` statement refers the use of [Traits.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Traits are a mechanism for code reuse.

A example from the php.net manual:

```
<?php
class Base {
    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'Hello ';
    }
}

trait SayWorld {
    public function sayHello() {
        parent::sayHello();
        echo 'World!';
    }
}

class MyHelloWorld extends Base {
    use SayWorld;
}

$o = new MyHelloWorld();
$o->sayHello();
?>
```